# page number in table of contents is right after the section name instead of at the end

Tags: table-of-contents

Hi my table of contents aligns all the page numbers at the end, except in the last line.
The bibliography entry has its pagenumber right after it says bibliography. Does any one know what i did wrong, or what i have to change, so that it aligns like the rest?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, UKenglish]{article}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{a}
    test
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not enough information shown.  Maybe check the `.toc` file.

Comment: You have given us no idea what you have done to mess up the normal output. Provide an MWE that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it. We are not reliable mind readers.

Comment: I changed my post. This produces an output in which the page number of bibliography is right after it instead of at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
\addcontentsline{section}{Bibliography}
```

as `article` class does not support `chapter` (not only as `\chapter` but also as sectioning name in the TOC).

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it!
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}